# Vue computed setter not working with checkboxes?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have a computed setter:

```
rating: {
    get() {
        return this.$store.state.rating;
    },

    set(value) {
        console.log(value);

        this.$store.commit('updateFilter', {
            name: this.name,
            value
        });
    }
}
```

This is linked to my rating like so:

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" :value="Number(value)" v-model="rating">
    {{ index }}
</label>
```

I expect the computed setter to log an array because when I use a watcher to watch for changes on the rating model I am getting an array.

Except whenever I use a computed setter like above it simply outputs `true` when a checkbox is selected or `false` when they are all deselected.

What is going on here, should I just be getting an array just as like with a watcher?

Comment: Is `this.$store.state.rating` an array?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`v-model` has somewhat ["magical"](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Checkbox) behavior, particularly when [applied to checkboxes](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Checkbox). When bound to an array, the checkbox will add or remove the value to/from the array based on its checked state.

It is not clear in your example what `value` is in `Number(value)`. It should be a value that you want included in the array when the box is checked.

Taking the example from the Vue docs linked above, I have modified it to use a computed, and it works as you might expect, with the `set` getting the new value of the array.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    checkedNames: []
  },
  computed: {
    proxyCheckedNames: {
      get() {
        return this.checkedNames;
      },
      set(newValue) {
        this.checkedNames = newValue;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="checkbox" id="jack" value="Jack" v-model="proxyCheckedNames">
  <label for="jack">Jack</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="john" value="John" v-model="proxyCheckedNames">
  <label for="john">John</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="mike" value="Mike" v-model="proxyCheckedNames">
  <label for="mike">Mike</label>
  <br>
  <span>Checked names: {{ checkedNames }}</span>
</div>
```